# DOCTYPE and fixed position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have got script where i need to count window height (jQuery) ... from some forums i found out that i have to use doctype (because without it, window height was still 8)

I used doctypec from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) (w3schools.com)

```
var vyska = $(window).height();
```

i have there fixed divs too. If i use doctype, fixed divs disappear but if i don´t use doctype, i will not be able to count window height.

if i place doctype into code, fixed div absolutely doesn´t get css so css for fixed div is empty. After removing doctype fixed div works fine.

Any ideas how to see fixed divs and be able to get window height ? btw i use Firefox 27.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use
            doctype html
And see fixed divs. If the body is overlaying it then add a z-index attribute to your CSS for the div elements. Also, you may also want to add the 100% attribute to the body's height and width element in said CSS. So the CSS could add this...

```
       div {z-index:9000;} 
      body {height:100%;width:100%;}
```

Comment: body {height:100%;width:100%;} did it ... z-index i had right

Comment: btw with body {height:100%;width:100%;} it also works without doctype